# Instagram images pulled via HTTPS not displaying

Tags: instagram

I have a site that is pulling in image thumbnails from instagram via the api. Late last night images from Instagram stopped being displayed. Showing only the alt text.

Below is an example of the image url.

https://photos-e.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-frc/10268988_1433304356922340_419312075_n.jpg

If I go directly to that URL, I get a certificate error (as seen below)

[image: instagram cert error]

Anyone know why I would be getting this error suddenly and what I might have to do to fix it?

Comment: I'm not an instagram user but the link seems to return an image just fine

Comment: It is a problem related to programming in the sense that a site that uses SSL and Instagrams API now having problems displaying the images. If there has been any changes related to the API causing this, I would like to know. I can see that this is not only affecting our site but many others. That is why I asked it here.

Comment: @FredrikJohansson What is the technical issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: The embed option circumvents this issue.  Use the short link in the api response and use the media embed on this page.. http://instagram.com/developer/embedding/ .. here is an example: https://instagram.com/p/nyTfd5ie7K/media?size=l

Comment: As a temporarily fix i have used this replace:
var fixed_src = '//igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn/'+oldsrc.split('/').pop();

Comment: I'm programming, and I have come across this exact same problem. It's definitely a programming problem in my mind. I'm going on the assumption that Instagram will fix the problem, but I wonder how long it might take. :-(

Comment: I also solved it temporary by just using http for the images. Looking forward to an update when anyone gets any information absout when the problem is solved. Thanks everyone for your feedback on the problem so far!

Comment: It looks like they just changed all of the problematic images that we were having back to fbcdn.com which resolved the issue

Answer (score 2):

The source of the problem is akamai:
http://revealingerrors.com/akamai_ssl

I contacted akamai, but they told me to contact Instagram and have them open a support ticket with them instead.

Comment: Please update this if Instagram gets back to you!

Comment: Thanks for your info! Let us know when you have got any answer.

Comment: Instagram just got back to me to report that the issue has been fixed. It was actually working again for me a day later, so hopefully it's working now for all of you as well.

Answer (score 1):

Their SSL Certificate is reported to be invalid. Thus Chrome/Firefox does not load images.

*photos-b.ak.instagram.com uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for the following names: *.akamaihd.net, *.akamaihd-staging.net, a248.e.akamai.net (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)*